# Applied Energistic - Keep infinite amout of items

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I've just switched my logistic pipes system for an AE system, and I'm having trouble with something.

My LP system auto crafted me triple compressed cobblestone when there was enough in my system to make a block. Currently my AE system has 61k cobblestone clogging  it up. I've taught it how to make the triple compressed, but I can't find a way to tell it to auto craft them as soon as it can.

Is this possible?

I have a molecular assembler set up with the required CPUs and patterns in order to craft the triple compressed.

Comment: I'm not too hot on ME crafting myself, but you could *almost* get what you want by just requesting an insane number of the highest level compressed stone you currently have access to. If you requested 2048 triple compressed you'd not have to worry about it until you'd picked up just shy of 1.5 million cobblestone, but by then you could have changed it up to sextuple compressed...

Comment: It is possible but it is sort of in a round about manner. You can set up an export buffer to a holding chest and request that the buffer keep a piece of triple compressed cobble in there. But you also set up an import buffer to just keep that chest empty. In this way the system will constantly try to make a piece of triple compressed cobble and put it in the chest.. then just suck it back into the system when it does do that. Also, not an answer because while its similar to things I have done, I can not test it right now.. and it may not be the best way to do it :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in AE1 you can set a precision export bus to *craft only* into an interface set to export the triple compressed,

you can keep a stack or 2 of normal cobble in the system using a level emitter to stop the export bus when the amount of cobble drops below some level

In AE2 you can use the Molecular Assembler directly: create a chain of them with the encoded patterns for compressed cobble and an export bus exporting cobble to the first and an interface collecting from the last, using a redstone card you can control the export of cobble like you could with AE1.

There is no need to set up a crafting CPU in this setup as the assemblers will be in single pattern mode

Answer (score 3):

You can make recipes for all of the compressed cobblestone, and then just ask the system to craft one of the much-higher-up ones. The system will wait for more cobblestone. You can still make other crafting requests while the system waits.

You will also have to ask for the recipe again if the system gets reset. This is just a good alternative if you don't want to build any extra blocks and don't mind making the crafting request only occasionally. Having an export bus on craft-only mode as per the other answer is preferable if you have the space.

Also note that if you also make recipes to get the stone out of compressed blocks, the crafter will just craft in circles, compressing and uncompressing cobblestone.

Comment: This also suffers from the problem that system resets will cancel the crafting jobs so they'll need to be setup again every time it happens.

Comment: @JonK Definitely. I've added it to my answer. This is definitely the less desirable alternative but it's still an alternative.